# How to call a string in a method using jquery ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

1. I want to be able to use a "string" as well on the ajax method.
2. If I am using the "string", how can i be able to add "where" again on the SQL statement
3. For more info please refer on this page: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Cascading-Dependent-Country-State-City-DropDownLists-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Model Code:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   using System.Web.Mvc;


   namespace tk3.Models
   {
      public class ViewModel
     {
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.depart = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.department = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.gender = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.dryclean = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> depart { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> department { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> gender { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> dryclean { get; set; }

   public int departId { get; set; }
   public int typegenderId { get; set; }
   public int genderId { get; set; }
   public int btntagId { get; set; }
   public int ServiceId { get; set; }
   public int gendertypeId { get; set; }
}
```

}

Controlller:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Mvc;

   using tk3.Models;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;

   namespace tk3.Controllers
  {
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        model.depart = PopulateDropDown("SELECT * FROM depart", "servgend", "departId");
        model.gender = PopulateDropDown("SELECT genderId, gender FROM gender", "gender", "genderId");
        return View(model);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string type, int value)
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        switch (type)
        {
            case "departId":
                model.department = PopulateDropDown("SELECT btntagId, btntag FROM department WHERE departId = " + value, "btntag", "btntagId");
                break;

            case "btntagId":
                model.dryclean = PopulateDropDown("SELECT typegenderId, type FROM dryclean WHERE btntagId = " + value, "type", "typegenderId");
                break;

            case "genderId":
                model.dryclean = PopulateDropDown("SELECT genderId, type FROM dryclean WHERE typegenderId = " + value, "type", "genderId");
                break;

            case "typegenderId":
                model.dryclean = PopulateDropDown("SELECT genderId, price FROM dryclean WHERE genderId = " + value, "price", "genderId");
                break;
        }
        return Json(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int departId, int btntagId, int typegenderId, int genderId, int gendertypeId, int ServiceId)
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        model.depart = PopulateDropDown("SELECT departId, servgend FROM depart", "servgend", "departId");
        model.gender = PopulateDropDown("SELECT genderId, gender FROM gender", "gender", "genderId");

        model.department = PopulateDropDown("SELECT btntagId, btntag FROM department WHERE departId = " + departId, "btntag", "btntagId");
        model.dryclean = PopulateDropDown("SELECT typegenderId, type FROM dryclean WHERE btntagId = " + btntagId, "type", "typegenderId");
        model.dryclean = PopulateDropDown("SELECT genderId, type FROM dryclean WHERE typegenderId = " + typegenderId, "type", "genderId");
        model.dryclean = PopulateDropDown("SELECT genderId, price FROM dryclean WHERE genderId = " + genderId, "price", "genderId");
        return View(model);
    }

    private static List<SelectListItem> PopulateDropDown(string query, string textColumn, string valueColumn)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tk"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        items.Add(new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Text = sdr[textColumn].ToString(),
                            Value = sdr[valueColumn].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

}

CSHTML:

```
        @model tk3.Models.ViewModel

        @{
          ViewBag.Title = "Index";
         }

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Request</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.departId, Model.depart, "Please select department")
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.btntagId, Model.department, "Please select service")
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.genderId, Model.gender, "Please select gender")
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.typegenderId, Model.dryclean, "Please select item")
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceId, Model.dryclean, "Please select item")
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("select").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("option").length <= 1) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });

        $("select").change(function () {
            var value = 0;
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                value = $(this).val();
            }
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
                data: '{type: "' + id + '", value: ' + value + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var dropDownId;
                    var list;
                    switch (id) {
                        case "departId":
                            list = response.department;
                            DisableDropDown("#btntagId");
                            //DisableDropDown("#id");
                            PopulateDropDown("#btntagId", list);
                            break;

                        case "btntagId":
                            list = response.dryclean;
                            DisableDropDown("#typegenderId");
                            //DisableDropDown("#id");
                            PopulateDropDown("#typegenderId", list);
                            break;

                        case "genderId":
                            list = response.dryclean;
                            DisableDropDown("#typegenderId");
                            //DisableDropDown("#id");
                            PopulateDropDown("#typegenderId", list);
                            break;

                        case "typegenderId":
                            list = response.dryclean;
                            DisableDropDown("#ServiceId");
                            //DisableDropDown("#id");
                            PopulateDropDown("#ServiceId", list);
                            break;



                    }

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function DisableDropDown(dropDownId) {
        $(dropDownId).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(dropDownId).empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
    }

    function PopulateDropDown(dropDownId, list) {
        if (list != null && list.length > 0) {
            $(dropDownId).removeAttr("disabled");
            $.each(list, function () {
                $(dropDownId).append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
    }


</script>
```

So I want to achieve something like this below on my controller and able to execute it on ajax code as well

example:

```
     [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string type, int value, string value2)
        {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        switch (type)
        {
            case "departId":
                model.department = PopulateDropDown("SELECT btntagId, btntag FROM department WHERE departId = " + value + "AND WHHERE services = " + value2, "btntag", "btntagId");
                break;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following ajax.

```
    url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
    type:"POST",
    data:JSON.stringify({type: id, value: value}),
    success: function (response)
```

Comment: Your code does not throw any error.So should I not pass the parameter of 'value2' and you must remember 'value' is an integer.

Comment: Yes, You can pass the value2 even though it is an integer. It will identify the expected function by the argument list.